# undefined value when edit using ajax

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

im trying to get data from my db using ajax. So in controller i got the id but when go to edit modal the id is undefined.

here the code in controller :

```
router.post('/ajax/edit_groups/:id', async (req, res) => {
    console.log("edit")
    let [data_group, err] = await model.getById(req.params.id)
    console.log(req.params.id)

    console.log(data_group)
    res.json(data_group)
});
```

ejs code :

```
<table id="groups_table" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width: 100%;font-size:14px;">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr style="text-align: center;">
            <th>Group Name</th>
            <th>Group Description</th>
            <th>Role</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <%  if(groupData){
            for(var i=0;i < groupData.length; i++){
            if(groupData[i].role == 1) groupData[i].role = "Admin";
            else groupData[i].role = "User";
        %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= groupData[i].name%></td>
            <td><%= groupData[i].desc%></td>
            <td><%= groupData[i].role%></td>
            <td> 
                <div class="text-center">
                <a href="#" class="data" title="Edit" data-id="<%= groupData[i].id%>">
                    <span class="fas fa-edit fa-lg"style="color: #000000; font-size: 15px;">
                </a>
                <a href="" title="Delete">
                    <span class="fas fa-trash-alt fa-lg" 
                     style="color: rgb(206, 17, 17); font-size: 15px;">
                </a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <% };%>
    <% }%>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

in here i got the data-id value.
edit modal code :

script in ejs :

```
$('.data').on('click', function(){
        axios.post('ajax/edit_groups/' + $(this).attr("data-id"))
        .then(function (response){
            console.log("in: ", $(this).attr("data-id"))
            $('#editGroups').modal('show');
            $('#id_group').val(response.data_group[0].id);
            $('#name').val(response.data_group[0].group_name);
            $('#desc').val(response.data_group[0].group_desc);
            $('#inputRole').val(response.data_group[0].role);

        }).catch(function (error){
            console.log(error)
    })
})
```

in here, the result of console log, the data-id is undefined.. so idk how to resolve this.. im still newbie in nodejs ejs

Comment: What is `this` in the inner function even referring to? Can you log `this`?

Comment: @TheFool im using $(this) for select the attributes of data-id..

Comment: yes so when you console.log(this) in the inner function. what is it?

Comment: @TheFool it show "Window {parent: Window, opener: null, top: Window, length: 0, frames: Window, …}" ...

Comment: and there is your problem. this is referring to the window and not the .data element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the `this` keyword inside the callback is referring to the window object and not to the .data element as you expect.

You can do something like the below.

I am storing the element in outer scope to remember the element that was clicked on, so we can access its dataset in the callback.

```js
$('.data').on('click', function(event){

        // here im storing the element
        //  you can probalby also access it with $(this) and store it
        const dataEl = event.target

        axios.post('ajax/edit_groups/' + dataEl.dataset.id)
        .then(function (response){

            // in the callback I access the element that is in the outer scope
            console.log("in: ", dataEl.dataset.id)

            $('#editGroups').modal('show');
            $('#id_group').val(response.data_group[0].id);
            $('#name').val(response.data_group[0].group_name);
            $('#desc').val(response.data_group[0].group_desc);
            $('#inputRole').val(response.data_group[0].role);

        }).catch(function (error){
            console.log(error)
    })
}
```

*Note: I did not test the code, Its just a to illustrate in which way the problem could be solved.*

You may want to look for alternative ways. You can actually use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) and some other methods when working with `this`.

Since you have an element inside the anchor tag, you need to make sure you don't capture its click events. That has to do with something called event delegation.

One simple way to achieve this is actually with CSS.

```css
 .data span { pointer-events: none; }
```

There are other options as well.

Comment: i tried this and still undefined and "Window {parent: Window, opener: null, top: Window, length: 0, frames: Window, …}"  :"..

Comment: hmm. what are you logging now? I am pretty sure this approach is what you need. All you need is to store the element somewhere

Comment: yess.. i logged this.. i tried logged dataEl but the result is the span tag.. i tried put the data class and data-id in span tag and the result its work, the id showed.. but it keep looping and the response is undefined..

Comment: Yes that's because you actually click the span and not the anchor. It's a bit tricky when it comes to those details. I update my answer to show you one way of how to deal with this kind of stuff. Using CSS.

Comment: well, that might be a completely different game. But I notice you are probably still using `'ajax/edit_groups/' + $(this).attr("data-id")` as your url. You may want to use the id from the element you know it is the right one now.

Comment: i already changed it.. i logged response.data_group[0] its undefined..

Comment: was it before the change comming fine?

Comment: no, before the change it doesnt show up the response

Comment: ah no I know that it is, you dont use axios properly. Read the docs. Reponse is laaaarge object. YOu only want resonse.data or response.body or something. Depends on the library. I guess it should be `response.data.data_group[0]`

Comment: I think response.data is the datagroup. Try also `response.data[0]` .

Answer (score 0):

Since ajax is asynchronous, you can't call the response directly. Try to add async await on your function like:

```
    $('.data').on('click', async function() {
    await axios
        .post('ajax/edit_groups/' + $(this).attr('data-id'))
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log('in: ', $(this).attr('data-id'));
            $('#editGroups').modal('show');
            $('#id_group').val(response.data_group[0].id);
            $('#name').val(response.data_group[0].group_name);
            $('#desc').val(response.data_group[0].group_desc);
            $('#inputRole').val(response.data_group[0].role);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    });
```

Comment: You are mixing async await with promise syntax. His syntax is valid, yours probably not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get id from data-id attribute

```
console.log("in: ", $(this).dataset.id)
```

For References
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Comment: His way should also work. What you do, is accessing the attribute via reflected property getter. Still, if that works, get attribute must also work. They are interchangeable.

Comment: the result is still undefined.. "Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"

Comment: It may be selecting class which return the array. Try assigning unique id while making loop and get id of clicked item and pass it to the